Авторизация на гугл странице с помощью requests или Oauthlib
Добрий день, у меня стоит задача заполнить и отправить данные на этом сайте: Click quantity form c помощью пайтон кода, и я столкнулся с проблемой:

Я не могу найти к какой Google API относится этот сайт( если относится вообще );
И при попытке спарсить этот сайт он просит меня залогинится.
Я пытался залогинится через google_auth_oauthlib но он все равно не пускает меня к самой форме. Возможно я указываю не те scopes, или не передаю нужные хедеры в запрос, может кто то уже сталкивался с такой задачей и знает как правильно реализовать авторизацию что бы получить доступ к этому сайту. Единственное что у меня получилось так это отправка запроса с __Secure-1PSID, __Secure-1PSIDTS в куках, но для меня это не решение так как я эти куки брал руками с браузера, а где их взять по другому я тоже не нашел..

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо !
Вот код, которым пытаюсь залогинится с помощью oauthlib:
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

# client-google.json is Credentials from google console
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client-google.json',
    scopes=[
        'openid', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    ]
)

credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'})

url = 'https://support.google.com/google-ads/contact/click_quality'
response = session.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_content = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    file_path = "google_ads_click_quality.html"
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(soup.prettify())
else:
    print("status code:", response.status_code)

В google_ads_click_quantity.html я получаю страницу авторизации гугла.
